# MySQL: Using GROUP BY vs subselect in columns list

Tags: mysql, subquery

In my application I have two MySQL tables, 'units' and 'impressions' in relation one to many. I need to fetch list of all ad units from units table but also fetch impressions count for each ad unit.

I have two SELECT queries to do this task (simplified for this example), first using sub-select:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM impressions WHERE impression_unit_id = unit_id) AS impressions_count,
    unit_id
FROM units;
```

and second using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(impression_id) AS impressions_count,
    unit_id
FROM units
LEFT JOIN impressions ON impression_unit_id = unit_id
GROUP BY unit_id;
```

Sub-select query runs for each record (ad unit) so GROUP BY looks smarter but it has one JOIN more. Which one to prefer for performance?

Comment: Try them both, and see how they perform... I would expect that the database would come up with the same execution plan for both of these queries, so I'd expect them to be identical in terms of performance...  However, I would re-write your second query to use a `left join` instead of a `right join` for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Michael you're right I've edited to use LEFT JOIN to point out the "main" table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` query will perform better.  The query optimizer might optimize the first query to use a join, but I wouldn't count on it since it is written to use a dependent sub-query, which will be much slower.  As long as the tables are properly indexed, `JOIN`s should not be a major concern for performance.

The first query, if it doesn't get optimized to use a `JOIN` will have to run the sub-query for each row in the unit table, where the `JOIN` query does it all in one operation.

To find out how the query gets optimized, run an `EXPLAIN` of both queries.  If the first one uses a dependent sub-query, it will be slower.

Comment: EXPLAIN mentions DEPENDENT SUBQUERY for the first one, I guess I should stick to GROUP BY, thanks!